# Is the --group option deprecated from kafka-console-consumer tool? if so, how can I set the consumer group using kafka-console-consumer.

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to run multiple consumer for the same topic under different group name using the command line tool - kafka-console-consumer.sh. When I set --group option, it fails with error 'group is not a recognized option'. This was working fine until I upgraded to the latest kafka version (kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2).

Comment: What version did you upgrade from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured a way out. The group option is no longer available for the console-consumer. If you need to specify the group, then you can do so by using the --consumer.config option. It takes the path to the consumer.properties file as input. It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can use group.id without config file like this :
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic test --consumer-property group.id=1

Answer (score 1):

`--group` is not available for `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh` in new API.

By default all consumers uses `config/consumer.properties` where `group.id=test-consumer-group`.
Create one property file anywhere, and put `group.id=<your-group-name>`.

And when you run your console-consumer, just add one new parameter as `--consumer.config <your-newly-created-property-file>`

`$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic <topic-name> --zookeeper <zk-server>:<zk-port> --consumer.config <new-property-file>`

Answer (score 0):

The group option works for me in version 2.0.0.